# IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio is broken after updating to version 7.0.0.00-20150402-2001

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I updated my IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio to the newest version 7.0.0.00-20150402-2001 via Eclipse > Help > Check for Updates. With the result that MobileFirst is no longer running. I am missing the MFPF special Run commands, in “About Eclipse” MobileFirst is missing, and .metadata.log contains tons of errors, starting with

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [668]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.worklight-shared-common; bundle-version="7.0.0"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.worklight.worklight-shared-common; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; singleton:="true"
   com.worklight.worklight-shared-common [689]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties; bundle-version="7.0.0"
       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; singleton:="true"
          com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties [685]
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider
       -> Export-Package: org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="1.45.0"
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.bouncycastle145.asn1
       -> Export-Package: org.bouncycastle145.asn1; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="1.45.0"
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.gson.annotations; version="[2.3.0,3.0.0)"
       -> Export-Package: com.google.gson.annotations; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="2.3.1"
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.bouncycastle145.x509
       -> Export-Package: org.bouncycastle145.x509; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="1.45.0"
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.gson; version="[2.3.0,3.0.0)"
       -> Export-Package: com.google.gson; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="2.3.1"
     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.json.java
       -> Export-Package: com.ibm.json.java; bundle-version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties"; version="7.0.0.00-20150402-2001"
```

Even the uninstall fails with `No action found for: com.worklight.studio.plugin.Clean`.

How can I fix my MFPF installation?

Comment: New eclipse, fresh workspace, fresh installation from marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fatal errors like the one described, while I am not sure why that happened, the best course of action is to use a fresh instance of Eclipse with a new workspace and then re-install the MFP Studio plug-in from the Eclipse Marketplace.